# Subtraction beyond 0 = 0

Tags: solidity

Im trying to find a cheap solution in Solidity where a uint256 type caluclation for 1000-1001 results 0. I know that i run into overflow problems here and cant use Safemath.

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract Subtract {

    function subtract(uint a, uint b) public pure returns(uint remainder) {
        if(b>a) return 0;
        return b-a;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.